# how to point and click on rviz map and output the position

Tags: ros, topic, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can any one tell me how to use mouse to click on a map in Rviz and get the position of this area. Then output it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/69019/how-to-point-and-click-on-rviz-map-and-output-the--position./) by [Rikardo](https://answers.ros.org/users/5410/rikardo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2013-07-25

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you add a grid and click on with 2D Nav Goal or 2D Pose Estimate. The result is wrote in the terminal and in the topic /initialpose or /move_base_simple/goal. It's only a 2D select but it can be useful. I don't know if a better way exists.

---

Originally posted by [jep31](https://answers.ros.org/users/2564/jep31/) with karma: 411 on 2013-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [searchrescue](https://answers.ros.org/users/1542/searchrescue/) on 2016-06-24**:
more specifically, you can do this

rostopic echo /initialpose

OR

rostopic echo /move_base_simple/goal

**Comment by [BluPlana](https://answers.ros.org/users/29054/bluplana/) on 2017-01-17**:
What then is the use of the botton "publish point" on rviz?

**Comment by [raspet](https://answers.ros.org/users/29434/raspet/) on 2017-04-21**:
It is published at /clicked_point

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Go to the Top menu in RVIZ and click on **Panels**. Under the Panels, tick **Selection**. Once Selection is enabled, it adds a new Panel called Selection. Then on the RVIZ gui press on **select** option which is beside **Move Camera** option.

**Then whatever points you select on the point cloud will displayed in the Selection panel.**

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) with karma: 1935 on 2017-05-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lochlomond](https://answers.ros.org/users/44598/lochlomond/) on 2019-08-19**:
but, the coordinate is only the relative position wrt the vehicle?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Open a new terminal and type `rostopic echo /clicked_point`

Open Rviz and use Publish a point tool .

Click anywhere on the map .

The result should be instantaneously displayed in the terminal where we have echoed /clicked_point

---

Originally posted by [Anchellon](https://answers.ros.org/users/40786/anchellon/) with karma: 51 on 2019-04-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [viswa_1211](https://answers.ros.org/users/40296/viswa_1211/) on 2019-05-30**:
I have been trying this. I could see that when I select the Publish Point tool, the cursor gets a pin location and when I click a point, it publishes the coordinates in that frame. But most times, the pin location does not appear on my screen. When I am clicking any point, the point does not get published. Am I missing out something?

**Comment by [moooeeeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/27965/moooeeeep/) on 2019-09-09**:
@viswa_1211 Unfortunately you need to be able to click on something, to publish that position as a point (i.e., you can't publish points in empty space). One way is to enable the grid. You can then click on the corners. It seems the points are given in the fixed frame that is currently used.

**Comment by [JiangxinKe](https://answers.ros.org/users/63578/jiangxinke/) on 2020-11-18**:
is anyone solving this problem ???